# What is differene between secondary namenode and passive namenode

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

What is the other namenode which we use in highavailabilty of namenode is known as and what are the other namenodes used in hadoop federation i am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hope this information solves your confusion
>
> **1)Namenode::**
>
> Namenode holds the meta data for the HDFS  Namespace
> information, block information etc. Namenode stores the HDFS
> filesystem information in a file named **fsimage**. Updates to the file
> system (add/remove blocks) are not updating the fsimage file , it will
> be appended to the edit log, Fsimage contains mapping of blocks to
> files and other file system properties called snapshot of namenode. When restaring, the namenode reads the
> fsimage and then applies all the changes from the log file to bring
> the filesystem state up to date in memory.
>
> **2)Secondary Namenode::**
>
> The secondary namenode periodically pulls these
> two(Edits nd fsimage) files, and the namenode starts writing changes to a new edits
> file. Then, the secondary namenode merges the changes from the edits
> file with the old snapshot from the fsimage file and creates an
> updated fsimage file. This updated fsimage file is then copied to the
> namenode.
>
> **3)FailOver NameNode or Passive Namenode(Only if HA enabled)::** Prior to
> Hadoop 2.0.0, the NameNode was a single point of failure (SPOF) in an
> HDFS cluster. Each cluster had a single NameNode, and if that machine
> or process became unavailable, the cluster as a whole would be
> unavailable until the NameNode was either restarted or brought up on a
> separate machine.  the above problems is addressed by providing the option of running two redundant NameNodes in an HA cluster, the Standby/Passive NameNode also performs
> checkpoints of the namespace state, and thus it is not necessary to
> run a Secondary NameNode, CheckpointNode, or BackupNode in an HA
> cluster. In fact, to do so would be an error.